# SharePoint web services and a multilanguage environment

Tags: web-services, listdata.svc, multilingual

I cam writing a console application that connects to a SharePoint 2010 server and manipulates data using listdata.svc. For example, I look for the 'Announcements' list and edit the 'Title' field.

I have looked at the files generated by adding a server reference, and I don't see the internal name of the fields anywhere. What happens if someone takes my console application and tries to use it on a french SharePoint server rather than an English one? Will it panic and fail because it can't find lists and fields by their English name, or will the references automatically be adjusted to look for 'Annonces' and 'Titre'?

As a side note, is it possible to read/set the value of a hidden column via listdata.svc?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some nice work around.
The first solution that you could implement is working with the GUID of the list and the column instead of the title.
Or you can deploy a service that you can ask for the list and it'll reply to you with the name of the list translated in the current language.

Comment: Does that mean I need to switch from using the web service to using the SharePoint COM?

Comment: no, you could do that in web services as well.

Comment: What changes I need to do that web service convert its output to in my current language "English".My sharepoint site default language is "Danish"